# Unexpected String From Win32 UuidToString() Call

Tags: winapi, guid, win32com, win32ole

I have a simple class that generates a GUID by calling CoCreateGuid(). I then pass the result to UuidToString().

Most of the time I get a string in the format:

e0e3e4b5-6f13-4043-b6c6-488c8b85cbd1

However, on a few machines the result looks something like this:

0-40:61:86:C2:4E:4F

Can anybody explain this unexpected behavior? Is the second form even a GUID?

UPDATE: I have found the source of the error and it turns out that UuidToString() is not returning the string I thought it was.

Thanks for all the answers.

Comment: Did you check for error codes in `CoCreateGuid` and `UuidToString`? And did you try `StringFromCLSID` rather than `UuidToString`?

Answer (score 1):

**Warning: This is only a guess!**

What you have there looks very much like an MAC-Address.

`CoCreateGuid` basically uses `UuidCreate`.
That one can use the computers network adapter to create a locally unique UUID.
My guess is, that on these machines something of their network configuration triggers a "bug" or something, and therefore the intermediate string is returned.

You could try using `UuidCreate` directly and using the `RPC_S_UUID_NO_ADDRESS` flag

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa379205(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking neither form /is/ a GUID because a GUID is a 128-bit number, not a string. I've never seen the second form but I can imagine an implementation where it would be defined as valid. Normally UuidCreate, UuidFromString etc. are implemented in rpcrt4.dll but I suppose you could have an alternative implementation. Pass the string to UuidFromString and check that function's return value. Be sure that it's implemented in the same DLL as the UuidCreate and UuidToString that gave you this suspicious GUID in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Bizarre.  RPC is an oddball API though, it's very old and quirks are heavily preserved.  I'd recommend you use StringFromGUID2() instead.  Having two ways to accomplish the same thing is always a telltale sign, later is better.